# Is there a standard way to authenticate applications to your web API?

Tags: web-services, authentication, standards

I'm looking at building a simple web app that will expose an API that lets third-party (well, written by me, but that's not the point) apps query for and modify user-specific data stored on the site.

Obviously I don't want to allow apps to be able to get user-specific information without that users consent. I would want some kind of application authentication where users allow an application they run to use the web API to access their information.

Is there a standard way to achieve this or does every app (i.e. [rememberthemilk](http://rememberthemilk.com)) just hack up a bespoke solution specifically for them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Will [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) work for you? That's the problem it was designed to solve.

Comment: Looks interesting. Seems to have a fairly active community, at least in Google Groups. Do you know if anyone use it though? RTM seem to use their own thing, as does twitter..? Google supports it (but also has their own thing).. just don't want to build to a 'standard' that noone uses, you know :P

Comment: According to ars, "it has had the developmental backing of individuals and employees of companies like Google, AOL, Yahoo, Twitter, Pownce, Six Apart, Blaine Cook (formerly of Twitter, now at Yahoo), and Mark Atwood.". Good enough for me :)

Comment: OAuth only covers one component of your API.  So unless the rest of your API follows a standard other people implement, it hardly matters if others use OAuth or not.

If OAuth works for you, use it.  It's got a workable model, it's been well-reviewed, and there are implementations available.

Answer (score 3):

Also be careful to access your web service via HTTPS if the data is traversing the Internet.  People take great pains to authenticate their web services, but then leave them vulnerable to network sniffing.

Comment: And to a large extent, if you use HTTPS a lot of the machinery in OAuth is unnecessary.  But OAuth has been designed to give certain protections to traffic on unencrypted channels.